# How do I approach these Diophantine equations?

Tags: diophantine-equations

I'm a high school student, so I think my question will be an easy one. I would like to know if there is an easy way of approaching these Diophantine equations:

$x=\frac{1}{2^{a}-3}$

$x=\frac{2^{b}+3}{2^{a+b}-9}$

$x=\frac{2^{b+c}+3*2^{c}+9}{2^{a+b+c}-27}$

$x=\frac{2^{b+c+d}+3*2^{c+d}+9*2^{d}+27}{2^{a+b+c+d}-81}$

As you can see, they follow a pattern, and there are indefinitely many of them, but approaching these 4 would be enough. Another important thing is that x,a,b,c,d,...>=1.

My guess is that the only solution to these equations is *x=1* and *a,b,c,d,...=2*.
However, I'm having a hard time proving that.

If there is no approach, would it be possible to solve something by using lattices?

Thanks!

Comment: Are $x,a,b,c,d$ restricted to being positive integers, non-negative integers, or just integers?

Comment: Yes, _x,a,b,c,d,...>=1_, so positive integers only, no 0 allowed.